# MissingPluginException with background handler for push notifications when using SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins

I have the following file which is based on the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) example on how to manage background messages (i.e. when the application is terminated or in the background).

The file currently contains the following:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'notifications.dart';

Future<dynamic> backgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

  print("backgroundHandler: $message");
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  print(prefs.getInt('latest_id'));

}
```

The application *does* receive the notification, which is revealed when it prints the contents of `message` but when I try and get the [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) the console presents me with the following messages and code execution stops:

```
I/flutter (17018): Unable to handle incoming background message.
I/flutter (17018): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @Uni I can clarify that the issue will persist even if I try to print a specific preference, but the issue seems to be generated by the `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` call (as I've tested it before trying to print the `prefs` object). I'll update the question.

Comment: You have find a solution for your issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know it's a little late, but I found a solution. I share it for the next ones who will have this issue.
You should add SharedPreferencesPlugin in your PluginRegistry :

```
SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"));
```

The complete class :

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
import io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        SqflitePlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("com.tekartik.sqflite.SqflitePlugin"));
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin"))
        SharedPreferencesPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin"));
    }

}
```

Comment: You are awesome!

Comment: you are a lifesaver.

Comment: I'm on Flutter 2.0.6 facing the same issue but the above classes are now either deprecated or unavailable. Do you know where I can find the new equivalent?

Comment: @JonasZebari did you solve your problem? I'm facing the same, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

just call before

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

this line on where you get value.

like.,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

String name = prefs.getString("Name");
```

Answer (score -1):

This solves my problem

dependency_overrides:
shared_preferences_android: 2.0.10